# Не работает css-loader на Windows 10

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Доброго времени суток, при запуске webpack выскакивает такая ошибка - Module not found: ERROR in ./js/components/Component.css
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./../../../node_modules/css-loader/index.js in D:\Myproject\client\js\components
 @ ./js/components/Component.css 4:14-86

webpack стоит версии 1.14.0
Может именно на винде такая лажа, потому что на Ubuntu все работало... Даже переставлял webpack правда 2 и выше не идёт на винду... Может кто-то имел опыт с таким? Спасибо!

```js
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname + '/client',
    devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
    entry: './js/app.js',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react','es2015','stage-0'],
                    plugins: ['react-html-attrs','transform-class-properties', 'transform-decorators-legacy'],
                    compact: true
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loader: 'json-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader',
            }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname+'/client',
        filename: 'app.min.js'
    },
    plugins: debug ? [] : [
            new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
            new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({mangle: false, sourcemap: false})
        ],
};
```

```js
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.21.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-react-html-attrs": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.3.13",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "eslint": "^3.13.1",
    "gulp-coffee": "^2.3.3",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.8",
    "mocha": "^3.2.0",
    "should": "^11.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "supertest": "^3.0.0",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^2.4.0"
  },
```

Думаю Что простые зависимости не нужны здесь)

Comment: Вы уверены, что ругается на css-loader, а не на файл со стилями для компонента Component.css?

Comment: на 10 css-loader работает без проблем

Comment: @AlexSlobodyansky  Честно, я не уверен что именно на него, но файл соответствует тому что был на ubuntu, имена классов идут кэмэлом... может проблема с вебпаком, или нужно какие-то еще параметры прописать? Спасибо за отзыв)

Comment: опубликуйте код вебпака и package.json

Comment: @AlexSlobodyansky думаю остальные зависимости не нужны?

Comment: а пробовали без участия process.env собрать бандл?

Comment: @AlexSlobodyansky К сожалению тоже самое... Спасибо за ваше время!) Пока буду все в один файл писать...